# Cloning content, appending and prepending

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am trying to built **an infinite scroll** both upwards and downwards, using the `isotope plugin`.

But I'm stuck yet again after getting some help here on stackoverflow. Unfortunately the content only gets cloned once, but my intention is to clone and append/prepend it every time as soon as the user reaches the bottom or the top of the page.

I'm new to jQuery and I would really appreciate if you could help me debug it.

http://jsfiddle.net/sqJqr/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $newElements = $(".isotope").first().children().clone();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
        $(".isotope").append( $newElements ).isotope( 'appended', $newElements );
        $isotope = $(".isotope").first().children().clone();
      }
      else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 1 ) {
        $(".isotope").prepend( $newElements ).isotope('reloadItems').isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
        $isotope = $(".isotope").first().children().clone();
      }    
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do an [infinite scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll). The isotope plugin is interoperable with the infinite scroll plugin so you shouldn't have a problem. Here is an example using both from [this](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/infinite-scroll.html) page:

```
$(function(){

      var $container = $('#container');

      $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.element'
      });

      $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
        nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        itemSelector : '.element',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
            img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
          }
        },
        // call Isotope as a callback
        function( newElements ) {
          $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
        }
      );


 });
```

Comment: yeah i've seen that, but I dont want to use new content, just clone the existing one. Is the infinite scroll plugin useful for that?

Comment: What if you just link to the current page?

Comment: Add in the `navSelector` and `nextSelector` to your js. Then add in HTML that links to current content: `<nav id="page_nav">
    <a href="#container"></a>
  </nav>` It's worth a shot.

Comment: doesn't work for me. Now I'm back to where I started from. Any other ideas?